# want enhanced select box for bootstap 3 or 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using bootstrap 3 (can upgrade to 4) and want to replace/enhance multiple-select select boxes so I can allow:

- drag/drop from one to the other and back
- muliline/wrapping select-options for long input

I have seen these questions asked but what is the 'current' recommended direction to do this?
Should I replace with ul (bootstrap lists), which would allow the drag/drop w html5 and program to be
selectable like a select box? I see some jquery add-ins out there but they appear to be old. eg jquery-ui has something that does this but the changelog was last updated 3 or 4 years ago. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a real answer on the recommended direction, as everyone has their own opinions. JQuery-UI is older, but works fine with the current JQuery (v3.4.1).

Comment: Thanks. your comment is also helpful to me. I had no idea which way to go.